# How can I get the modified value on firebase realtime transaction?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

Im working on a script that need to execute simultaneous a list and set a propertie erase to true. Them, I would use the value to do some stuff, so I need it to return which one has been modified. I know that I can get the full modifie value in the parameter `snapshot` but is there anyway to get only the modified one?

Example:

```
 this.database.ref(refQuery).transaction(function(messages) {
        if(messages) {

          var arrayMessages = []
          let values = Object.values(messages)
          let keys = Object.keys(messages)

          for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if(!values[i].erase) {
              arrayMessages.push({ key: keys[i], value: values[i] })
            }
          }
          console.log('modified',messages[arrayMessages[0].key])
          messages[arrayMessages[0].key].erase = true;

        }
        return messages;
      }).then(({ committed, snapshot }) => {
        //Get the value changed, where is it?
        //I would like to get the messages[arrayMessages[0].key] value object.
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in for that, so you'll have to roll your own solution.

A simple approach is to store that property you modified in a variable at a higher scope, and then use that in the final `then()`.